# What is the best data structure to store playing cards held in a player's hand?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, collections

I'm beginner in java and I'm currently creating a card game like gin rummy for Android.  I want to know what's the best implementation for creating Hand class?  What's the best way where to store the card returned by Deck.dealt()?

1. Array
2. ArrayList
3. Vector
4. HashSet
5. LinkedList

Also, I would appreciate if anyone could provide a gin rummy open source links.

Comment: My advice: learn the differences between the collections (e.g. what's the difference between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`?), try something yourself and then come back with more specific questions. For the differences between the collections you might try and refer to the JavaDoc on each of those.

Comment: @Thomas - I have already checked the above collections, so I could say I understood it. I just can't decide which one to use because reading lots of card game open source they have different implementation that's why I wanted to know what's the ideal to use when creating a Hand class.

Comment: You should be able to decide that yourself. Just get all your requirements and select the datastructure that fits the best. Some requirements might be:  Are multiple equal objects allowed? Is ordering needed? Do you know the maximum number of cards and what's the ratio between max and average number of cards? How often do you read from/write to the structure? Do you need efficient random access or will you loop over all entries anyways? ...

Comment: Generally (assuming standard 52 card deck) none of these is particularly better than another since sorting, iterating, adding and removing basic objects from a set that is at its largest 52 elements will never be noticibally expensive with either space or time (unless you pull some kind of infinite loop). I would recommend any dynamic data structure for the practice though.

Comment: @Thomas - just for the sake of my question, what would be your choice? I appreciate if you could give me one.

Comment: Well, if you have the standard 52 card deck (i.e. only one card of each type) I'd probably go with a `LinkedHashSet` or `TreeSet` to get set semantics and some ordering (choice depends on which ordering you want). Alternatively, a map might also be an option, e.g. `Map<CardType, Card>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Store them in an `ArrayList`.**

Cards in a hand are in a certain order, not in an unordered pile.  This ordering is preserved in a `List` over a `Set`.

`ArrayList` also gives you the opportunity to select a specific card by index, which will be helpful as you implement the game.

Keep in mind that as long as you design your `Hand` class properly, you can always change this data structure easily at any point in the future.  As long as you keep this in mind with any class you design, you can always change it if you realize you need something different.

Comment: it depends on whether you can have multiple instances of the same card or only one (e.g. in a poker game). I'd not make the internal representation depend on the ui presentation since that order could be added later or by using an appropriate collection like  `LinkedHashSet` which has set semantics _and_ ordering (order of insertion) when using the iterator.

Comment: I'm not making it depend on the UI presentation.  I don't know of a single card game where cards in your hand are kept in an unordered pile.

Comment: Well, if you are allowed to have at most one card of a type you need some set semantics. With a list you'd have to loop over the entire list to check that. Additionally, if I do card games (the analog ones :) ), the order of the cards in my hand is at times quite arbitrary.

Comment: @Thomas Are you saying you're only allowed to have one card of a type because there's only one of each card in the deck?  If this is the case, it's enforced by there only being one object for that card.  If it's in your hand, then it can't be in the draw pile, discard pile, on the tableau, or anywhere else.  So you don't have to worry about this.  If it is a limitation, say you're playing with a double deck and can only have one card of any type, then you can handle this case individually.  I'm curious if there's a specific game you're talking about, because I've never run into this.

Comment: Well, I didn't have any specific game in mind. You can use a list and handle cases in which you can only have one type of card elsewhere but if the requirements imply set semantics I'd use a set (as I said, there are ordered sets) and not work around that with a list and some custom code. The basic point would be: the choice of structure should be based on the requirements and shouldn't be handled in a generic way (like always using a list).

Comment: I don't agree with Erick, the answer depends on the game, and I don't see why the deck should be ordered, usually you get one card and it is is not necessary that it is the first, or to know it in advance.

Comment: @greuze We're talking about the hand, not the deck.  OP wants to know the best way to store the card returned by `Deck.dealt()` when putting it in a hand.

Comment: @ErickRobertson I don't agree, a Hand and the Deck can have the same behaviour. Your cards in the hand doesn't need to be ordered, why should them?

Comment: @greuze I would agree that I would use the same behavior for a deck and a hand.  I would order them both.  Cards in a deck and cards in a hand are all ordered by nature.  There is a top card in the deck, then a next one, then a next one.  The same is true of a hand.  There is a card on top which appears on the left when fanned.  The next card is next to it, and so on.  This affects the order in which the user sees his cards.  For most card games, most players sort their cards in some way, too.  This requires ordering.

Answer (score 24):

If you really want to understand the nuances between the collection types, here goes.

`List` isn't technically appropriate except when the game is [Bohnanza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohnanza) (which, ahem, is one of the greatest card games of all time, but I'mma let me finish).

`List` says, among other things, that one hand containing the Ace and King of Clubs, and another hand containing the King and Ace of Clubs, are fundamentally *not the same hand.* This is a much stronger dependence on order than simply "well, I want to remember the order that the user wants to see their cards in", which is a property that tons of non-List collections have, like `LinkedHashSet` and Guava's `ImmutableSet`.

`List` also implies that there is some particular significance attached to the card that sits in index N.  This is true of no card game I know.

`Set` isn't generally appropriate for card games -- only the ones that use a single deck of completely unique cards.

To allow duplicates but still have order-independent equality, the type to use is Guava's `Multiset`.  For example `HashMultiset` or `ImmutableMultiset`. Note that most multiset implementations represent multiple "equal" cards by storing just the card and a count, so when iterating over them, duplicates of a card you have in your hand must always appear together. If it's important to let the user freely control the order of cards in her hand, you would need `LinkedListMultiset`.

Now that lesson time is over.... well, let's be honest. Calling `myHand.equals(yourHand)`, or using an entire hand as a key in a `Map` is not *actually* something you're ever going to do... so go ahead and use the `ArrayList`, you'll be fine. :-)

Comment: I disagree that using a `List` says that two hands with different orders of cards are not the same.  That is only true if you pass your `Hand.equals()` implementation down to `List.equals()`, which I would not do.  If I'm ever putting a `Hand` in a `HashMap` (for example), I want two different hands which contain the same cards in the same order to still be considered different hands and return `false` from the call to `Hand.equals()`.

Comment: Yeah, your way of thinking of it is a lot closer to what you'd actually do in real life.

Answer (score 3):

I think a good idea would be to use an interface (List if element are ordered, or Set if elements are not ordered. You can use the implementation you prefer, for example:

```
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

or

```
Set<Card> deck = new HashSet<Card>();
```

Comment: -1 Part of the question Zack is asking is whether he should use an ordered list or unordered collection.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a `HashSet` is faster(as far as I know), but if you want to make a card game, then maybe you will wish to sort the cards. That is why I would suggest using a List. If you are a beginner, then maybe the best thing would be to use an `ArrayList`. It's easy to use and understand. At least this is what I would do. If you want to learn more, I suggest reading about each one's unique properties so that you can decide for yourself. And yes, like greuze said before, you should use an interface for more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use of Vector is discouraged in the latest versions of Java, so you can probably ignore that one.

Secondly, as you'll know if you're read the Javadoc on those remaining classes, they all have advantages or disadvantages. Some have an order, some can take duplicate values, some cannot and so on. Therefore I think the best approach is to write some pseudo-code for your application which is not based on a specific class (just write things like 'add Card to Hand', 'remove card from Hand'). Once you have some of this pseudo code you will be able to see your requirements more clearly; will you want to keep the cards in the hand in a specific order? will you want to be able to retrieve cards from the hand by a key?

Then, your choice will be clearer.

Comment: @use1168884 - that make sense. Also, reading some of Java best practices, HashSet outperformed both Vector and ArrayList when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the deck in a List makes sense as it does maintain order. I tend to default to using Lists.newArrayList() to create a List. Lists is part of Guava. I *strongly* recommend using and getting to know Guava since it has many useful offerings.

It would make sense to be able to keep the hand in some data structure that could be sorted easily in order to make it easier to compare hands. OTOH, IIRC, gin rummy hands aren't all that large.